# Calling scripts and variables between them iteratively in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, scripting, iteration

I am trying to authomatise a script that:

- reads an input defined in another script (e.g. Input_01.py, or Input_02.py, just containing a variable definition such as: J = 6 or J = 7); and
- use that variable within a function, i.e.:

  ```
  def foo_function():

      A = J
      A += 3
      print(A)
  ```

Now, if I don't need to authomatise anything, the thing is pretty straightforward:
I just type `from Input_01 import J` and that's it. Then I can do the same for Input_02 and repeat the operation. 
But my idea is to make a script (Multi_Run.py) that allows me to authomatise the process of calling several times the key script (called "code_foo.py"), one for each Input file, and each time reading a different Input file (e.g. Input_01, Input_02,..., etc.)

This is my current "Multi_Run.py" script (simplified for the case of just two different input files):

```
Inputs = []
for i in range(2):
    Inputs.append("Input_0%s" % (i+1))


for Counter in Inputs:
    import code_foo
    code_foo.foo_function()
```

But now I cannot say, within "code_foo.py", something like: `from Counter import J`, because that won't work for two reasons:

1. First, Counter is not a variable in code_foo (this seems to be solvable by adding a line like `from __main__ import *`)
2. Second, the import function is not able to read the string inside the Counter variable, but it wants directly the name of the module (e.g. Input_01), preventing authomatisation. I tried to solve this by using the importlib.import_module but it's not seeming to work properly (i.e. the "Input_##" module is "imported" somehow, but not "run", which means that the "J=#somenumber" line is not run when importing the script and thus I get an error because the J variable is not defined).

For better clarity, my current code_foo.py script is the following:

```
import importlib


from __main__ import *

importlib.import_module(Counter)


def foo_function():

        A = J
        A += 3
        print(A)
```

Any hints? thanks a lot

Comment: "is not seemin to work properly" is a totally useless description of a problem. Please post your code (or at least a MCVE) and a complete description of how it "doesn't work" (if you get an exception, post the exact error message AND the full traceback, else describe the expected result and the result you get instead).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, well I already posted almost the entire code, so let me recap: I have the Multi_Run.py script (just as posted), two Input_##.py scripts just containing "J = #a number" (as already said), and the code_foo.py script, which is currently like this:
`
import importlib


from __main__ import *

importlib.import_module(Counter)


def foo_function():
        
        A = J
        A += 3
        print(A)`

The problem is that the import with importlib is not "running" the imported script, as it would do with normal import, so variable J is "unknown"

Comment: please edit your question - code in comments is barely readable.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I edited the the question. If you have any solution I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT (your question is still quite unclear), it looks like you have two issues here.

The first one is about Python's imports and namespaces. Python imports are not "includes" à la C or PHP so importing a module doesn't make the names defined in the module directly available in the importer's namespace, you have to use the qualified name ("."). Also, Python doesn't have a "process global" namespace, Python's "globals" are only global to the current module's namespace, so defining a global name in module "a" doesn't make it magically available to modules imported by module "a". This means that your `foo_function` in `code_foo.py` cannot directly access names defined in your main script.

Actually - and this is the second issue - your problem comes from `foo_function` depending on a global name that is defined elsewhere. This is a design mistake. As a general rule, you should not use globals when you don't need them, and you very rarely need globals. Just write your functions so they take "external" values as argument, and everything becomes much simpler AND much easier to read, test and maintain.

In your case, all you need to do is to 1/ rewrite `foo_function()` so it takes `J` as an argument and 2/ rewrite `multirun` so that it gets `J` from your "inputs" modules and passes it to `foo_function`:

```
# code_foo.py

def foo_function(j):
    a = j
    a += 3
    print(a)
```

and

```
# multirun.py

import importlib
import code_foo

def main():
   inputs = ["Input_0%s" % i for i in range(1,3)]

   for modname in inputs:
       module = importlib.import_module(modname)
       j = module.J 
       code_foo.foo_function(j)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As a side note: python's naming conventions are to use all_lower names for modules and variables - ALL_CAPS names are for pseudo-constants.